# What ensures that assembler alignment directives are obeyed at runtime?

Tags: assembly, linker, gnu, memory-alignment

I'm writing a function `foo` in assembly, and for various reasons the first
instruction of the function must land at an address with a certain alignment
within virtual memory when the binary is executed. For example, in the code
below I've requested 13-bit alignment, so the address of the function at runtime
must be a multiple of `0x2000`.

It seems natural to do this:

```
// The function must be aligned to 2^ALIGNMENT_BITS bytes.
#define ALIGNMENT_BITS 13

.text
.p2align ALIGNMENT_BITS
foo:
    [...]
```

However, the [GNU assembler documentation](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html) says only that `.p2align` pads
the location counter within the assembler, not that any alignment information
will ultimately make it to the binary. So, for example, if this is the first
directive within the file, it is a no-op. I worry that if the resulting object
file is linked with other object files, it may simply be concatenated to an
arbitrary address.

1. Will the alignment information somehow make it into the object file
   generated by the assembler? If so, what is the mechanism, and is this
   documented somewhere?
2. Similarly, does the final binary contain the necessary alignment information
   to ensure that the OS maps the text section to an appropriate base address in
   virtual memory?

You can assume Linux here, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

In ELF object files (e.g, on Linux), the largest alignment value present in a section is propagated to the alignment of the section. For instance, compiling the code you provided above and running `objdump -h` on it shows that the section has an alignment of `2**13`:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00200000  00000000  00000000  00100000  2**13
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
```

Note that the same is also true if the `.p2align` is present somewhere else in the section. Otherwise, if the section were shifted by a smaller amount, it would violate the alignment inside the section!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was imagining. I'm looking for two more pieces of detail:

1. Is this documented somewhere? Perhaps I'm just reading the linked assembler
documentation for `.p2align` too strictly, but it doesn't say anything about
informing the linker.

2. I assume a similar thing happens when N object files are linked in to a
binary–the maximum alignment constraint for each section is chosen?